# Jbutton event handler not working properly

Tags: java, swing, scope, jbutton

```
rollDice.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //generate roll
            int roll = dice.getRoll();

            addGameFeedMessage(players[1].getName() + " rolled " + roll);

            //store the player's position before the roll
            int currentPlayerPos = players[1].getPosition();

            //update player's position
            players[1].movePlayer(roll);

            //move the player icon to the player's position
            tiles[players[1].getPosition()].addIconCurrentPlayersPanel(players[1].getPlayerIcon());

            //revalidate components
            //tiles[currentPlayerPos].getCurrentPlayersPanel().revalidate();
            //tiles[players[1].getPosition()].getCurrentPlayersPanel().revalidate();
            //this loop was put in to see if doing revalidate() on all panels would make a difference but the problem is still there
            for(int i = 0; i < tiles.length; i++)
            {
                tiles[i].getCurrentPlayersPanel().revalidate();
            }
    }
});
```

Can anyone explain why the for loop in the actionListener for roll dice doesn't seem to work yet the for loop just above it which is the exact same thing works? There's no actual error as such it just doesn't do anything, however it does get inside the actionListener and executes as we've put print statements etc in it.

Guessing its something strange about actionListeners but I'm not sure what.

Any assistance would be appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Have you print the `getNumOfPlayers()` in `actionPerformed` before the for loop?

Comment: @skirsch Fixing indention is fine, but changing coding style is considered too radical a change. The person who approved your edit should have known this...

Comment: @Lundin alright, I'll give it another shot ;)

Comment: @VishalK I printed the getNumOfPlayers it's always the same, it's nothing to do with that. Seemingly just doesn't execute anything inside that for loop for some reason.

Comment: Have you put `System.out.print`  within the for loop ? Is that printing something?

Comment: @VishalK Yeah, it prints fine inside the for loop. currentPlayersOnTile[5].add(players[i].getPlayerIcon()); That line just doesn't execute or doesn't do what its supposed to for some reason and FYI its adding a JPanel to a JPanel.

Answer (score 1):

You should call [`validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#validate%28%29) after the `for loop` as follows:

```
for(int i = 0; i < getNumOfPlayers(); i++)
{
    currentPlayersOnTile[5].add(players[i].getPlayerIcon());
}
validate();
```

For Example consider the code given below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
class DemoPanels extends JFrame
{
    public void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        JButton button = new JButton("Click");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
            {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
                {
                    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
                    panel1.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(i)));
                    panel.add(panel1);
                }
                validate();//comment this line and then compile and execute the code to see the effect
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                DemoPanels dp = new DemoPanels();
                dp.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*NOTE: comment the code `validate()` and then compile and execute it to see the effect.*

Comment: That didn't make a difference, even if that line wasn't in a for loop it still does nothing despite working properly just above the addActionListener method(with or without the for loop). Makes no sense at all as to why it doesn't work. The only place it doesn't work is inside that method which is exactly where it needs to be sadly.

Comment: Did you try this solution? call `validate` on the `JFrame` on which you have added `currentPlayersOnTile[5]` `Panel`

Comment: Yes I tried it. It did absolutely nothing. There's nothing wrong with the line `currentPlayersOnTile[5].add(players[i].getPlayerIcon());`. That exact line (changing only 5 or i to other values) is used above to put the icons on the first tile at `currentPlayersOnTile[0]` therefore it's a problem with it being inside this button event handler.

Comment: I have edited the code a bit. Hope it makes a bit more sense.

Comment: You should `revalidate()` the panel that changed, not the entire frame.

Comment: @camickr Cheers mate that worked perfectly. Whats the reason for having to call it though so I can understand it better as I will probably need to use it quiet a bit in this project as I have a swing GUI.

Comment: `revalidate()` works sometimes but not all the time (after further testing).
anyone have any idea why it would work sometimes and not others? I'll update the code above to show what I have done.

Comment: Fixed the problem, was on another stackoverflow thread and read this: 
1/ if you adds a new JComponent to the Container then you have to call

validate();
repaint(); //lay with LayoutManager required that 
2/ if removes and then adds a JComponents from/to the Container then you have to call

revalidate();
repaint(); // lay with LayoutManager required that

Comment: @GrahamKelly: so you called `revalidate()` followed by `repaint()`?

Comment: Sorry only seeing this now - Yeah that's what fixed the problem, seems any time you change what's on a JPanel it has to be called or the updates don't take place